# eval throws Insecure dependency in eval while running setuid in perl 5.10.1 , work fine in 5.8.8

Tags: perl

```
eval("local our ".$custom_fields_hash->{ $id }->{ 'name' });
```

throws

> "Insecure dependency in eval while running setuid"

in perl 5.10.1.

works fine in 5.8.8

Comment: Taint error aside, I question the correctness of `eval('local our ...')`, although it's hard to tell since you didn't show the complete statement. You appear to be trying to use a variable as a variable name. Please read "[Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)"

Comment: @ikegami I'm not sure `local our …` even makes any sense outside of an `eval`. OP: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @duskwuff, It does, but its uses are limited: dynamic scoping, "lexical" that isn't captured by closures. Generally, you'd want a truly lexically-scoped variable instead. I think they are trying to create a lexically-scoped variably-named variable.

Comment: Don't replace one question with another. (Also, the new question was awful in both format and content.)

Comment: @ikegami sorry for the  confusion. Is there way I can remove taint error , remove the setuid bit . please can you suggest.

Comment: I told you everything I could given the information provided (i.e. a partial Perl statement)

Comment: @ikegami : I tried following stuff to untaint. But did not help                               if ($data =~ /^([-\@\w.]+)$/) {
 $data = $1;    # $data now untainted
    } else {
 die "Bad data in '$data'";  # log this somewhere
    }

Comment: @Prabhakar Bhatt S, so?

Comment: @ikegami  Thanks for your support. (i.e. a partial Perl statement) . you need full code?

Comment: NEVER. Normally, we'd need a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem. In this case. In this case, it sounds like you are trying to do something without knowing how to do it, so you're question is probably along the lines of "How do I <task the code is suppose to perform>?" Include your work. But again, only post code that relates the question.

Comment: @ikegami I have added the code snipped. Thanks a lot once again

Comment: Earlier, I mentioned I suspected your code is trying to create variables. I was correct. As I mentioned then, [that makes no sense](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). Stop doing that (e.g. by storing your config vars in a hash) and your issue will go away.

Comment: @ikegami  Thanks once again. I am not a perl developer. So I have zero knowwledge here. if you give me an example how to break it , that will be of great help. Thanks once again.

Comment: Then this should be easy, because the correct thing to do in other languages is also the correct thing here. If you want to lookup values by name, don't try to create variables; use an associative array (dictionary). Hashes are associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ikegami. let me try this.

Answer (score 2):

You have it backwards. The security check works fine in 5.10.1, but didn't in 5.8.8.

You're running in taint mode (because you're running in setuid mode) and you're apparently passing code from an unstrusted source to `eval`. That's a major security violation, so Perl prevents you from doing it.

Read more about it in [perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html).

Comment: Thanks for ur inputs. following is the snipppet.                                                    my ($in_file_name, $separator_char) = @_;
  my %custom_fields_description = ();
  open FILE, "< $in_file_name" or return;
  while(<FILE>){
    chop;
    my($name,$id,$type)= split($separator_char);
    $::trc->print( $::dbg,"found id $separator_char");
    $custom_fields_description{$id}{name} = $name;
    $custom_fields_description{$id}{type} = $type;
  }
 close FILE;
 return \%custom_fields_description;

Comment: for my $id ( keys %$custom_fields_hash )
    {                                                                                                    
  eval("local our ".$custom_fields_hash->{ $id }->{ 'name' });                                 }

Comment: @PrabhakarBhattS please edit your code into your question. It's hard to read in a comment without formatting.